# How to count number of columns that have a value by a grouping variable in R?

Tags: r, pattern-matching, data-manipulation

I have data like this:

```
repetition Ob1 Ob2 Ob3 Ob4
1           0   0   0   1
1           0   0   3   0
1           1   3   3   0
1           2   3   3   0
2           4   0   2   2
2           4   0   3   0
2           0   0   0   0
3           0   0   0   0
3           4   0   4   0
3           0   0   0   0
```

I want to count the number of columns per repetition that have a certain value e.g. 1.

So in this case repetition 1 should return a 2 because Ob1 and Ob4 have a value of 1. Everything else gets a 0 because there are no other repetitions with a 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `by` like:

```
by(x[-1]==1, x$repetition, function(y) sum(colSums(y) > 0))
#INDICES: 1
#[1] 2
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#INDICES: 2
#[1] 0
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#INDICES: 3
#[1] 0
```

or to return a named vector

```
c(by(x[-1]==1, x$repetition, function(y) sum(colSums(y) > 0)))
#1 2 3 
#2 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get count using `dplyr` package below code:

```
df$count <- rowSums(df[,2:5] == df$repetition)
df %>% select(repetition, count) %>% group_by(repetition) %>% summarise(count = sum(count))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  repetition count
       <int> <dbl>
1          1     2
2          2     2
3          3     0
```